# Secondary external hard disk not detected

Tags: 16.04, external-hdd

I am trying to transfer data from one external hard disk to other. However, when one is connected, another one doesn't connect, and vice-versa. It doesn't even show up on "fdisk -l". Nautilus does not show it either.

Has anyone faced similar problem? Is there any way to mount the second external hard disk?

OS : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (latest updated), 
Laptop : Lenovo Z Ideapad

Comment: Your laptop may not be providing enough power. Run `dmesg -w` and connect the disks to see what errors the kernel reports.

Comment: Are these disks clones of each other? If they both have the same UUID this will occur. Connect one disk at a time and do `sudo blkid` and compare UUID's.

Comment: Thanks muru and heynnema. It does seem to be power issue (I found several errors saying unable to power the device). Funny thing is after restart my lappy is able to power both of them. Seems like a non-issue now. Thanks for your help.